# How can I redirect this contact form to a specific permalink

Tags: permalinks, forms, contact

I'm converting a HTML site to WP for a client and they have a simple contact form in place.

If the submission is sucessful it currently, in it's HTML form, sends them to thankyou.html but I want to be able to send it to a custom permalink (Ie; to a page with the ID of 8) within the new installation, is it possible with the following code?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$to = "DESTINATION@EMAIL.COM";
$subject = "Web Site Form Enquiry";
$name_field = $_POST['contactname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone_no'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];

$headers = "From: $email_field \r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";
$body = "From: $name_field\r\n Address: $address\r\n Telephone: $phone_field\r\n E-Mail: $email_field\r\n Enquiry:\r\n $enquiry\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
{
    // This needs to change to the permalink of a page with the ID of 8
        header('Location: ../../thankyou.php');
}
else 
{
    // This needs to change to the permalink of a page with the ID of 12
    header('Location: ../formerror.html');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your form has been incorporated into WordPress as a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), which I encourage, then [`get_permalink(8); // or 12`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) should do it.

If not, then `http://example.com/?p=8` and `http://example.com/?p=12` should always work. `http://example.com/?page_id=8` and `http://example.com/?page_id=12` uses the proper parameter for pages but `?p=` works fine when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all you fields like this:

Step1.

```
//if form submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {



// use this for all fields 
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) === '') {
        $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }


// this is for email
if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

if(trim($_POST['message']) === '') {
        $messageError = 'Please enter a message.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $message= stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $message= trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }

    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
        }
        $subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";
        $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
 ?>
```

Step2. Correct errors

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
    <div class="thanks">
        <p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                <p class="correct_errors">Please correct the highlighted errors and try again..<p>
            <?php } ?>
```

Step 3. Your form

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactform" method="post">

<p class="error_s"><?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
    <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
    <?php } ?></p>
    <p><label for="contactName" class="cContact">Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"  name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField inputas" style="width:190px;" /></p>

....do the same for other inputs...

<p class="error_s">
<?php if($messageError != '') { ?>
<span class="error"><?=$messageError;?></span>
<?php } ?>
    </p>
<label for="message" class="cContact">Message</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="comments" id="message" class="requiredField" cols="48" rows="10" ><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['message']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitt" value="Send your message" style="cursor:pointer">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

</form>
```

It's easy to do it even it looks different. All you need is to try more!

If still want to redirect to another page then use this:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
{
    // This needs to change to the permalink of a page with the ID of 8
         wp_redirect( 'http://yourdomain.com/succes/', 301 ); exit;
}
else 
{
    // This needs to change to the permalink of a page with the ID of 12
    wp_redirect( 'http://yourdomain.com/error/', 301 ); exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately I can't change the form code. Had I done it myself originally I'd have done it in a very similar way, but my client (who is in turn doing this for another client) wants to keep everything as is